# Junit executing via ANT keep getting Class not found Exception

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have search and Googled for this, but cannot get it to work!
The script compiles and creates my jar file, no problem
I can run my unit tests from Eclipse, but get a Class NOT Found exception when running using the ANT builder.
Here is the full error reported by Junit:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CustomerTest
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:139)
```

This is the build.xml segment

```
<property name="src_dir" value="src/com/biscom/fadb8"/>
<property name="build" value="bin"/>
<property name="classes_dir" value="${build}/classes"/>
<property name="dist" value="dist"/>
<property name="lib_dir" value="lib"/>
<property name="reports" value="${build}/junitreports"/>
<property name="junit_dir" value="c:\junit"/>

<path id="classpath">
     <fileset dir="${lib_dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
     <pathelement location="${junit_dir}/junit-4.12.jar"/>
     <pathelement location="${junit_dir}/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
</path>

<path id="classpath_junit">
     <fileset dir="${lib_dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
     <pathelement location="${junit_dir}/junit-4.12.jar"/>
     <pathelement location="${junit_dir}/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
     <pathelement location="${build}/classes"/>
</path>

<target name="junit" depends="createdist">
<junit printsummary="yes">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="classpath_junit"/>
            <path refid="application"/>
         </classpath>
         <formatter type="xml"/>
         <batchtest fork="no" todir="${reports}">
            <fileset dir="${src_dir}" includes="CustomerTest.java"/>
         </batchtest>
    </junit>

    <junitreport todir="${reports}">
        <fileset dir="${reports}" includes="TEST-*.xml"/>
        <report todir="${reports}"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

Here is the CustomerTest class:

```
public class CustomerTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public final void testGetAccounts() 
    {
        ArrayList<Customer> list = Customer.getAccounts(Customer.OFFICE, Customer.STATUS_NONE);
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull("should not be null", list);
        int counter = list.size();
        org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(counter > 0 );
    }

    @Test
    public final void testGetAccountsInvArgs()
    {
        ArrayList<Customer> list = Customer.getAccounts(5, Customer.STATUS_NONE);
        org.junit.Assert.assertNull("should be null", list);
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant part of Customer.java:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public static ArrayList<Customer> getAccounts(int accountType, int status)
        {
            logger.info("getAccounts. start");
            if (accountType < Customer.OFFICE || accountType > Customer.ENTERPRISE)
            {
                logger.error("getAccounts. invalid accountType: " + accountType);
                return null;
            }
        ArrayList<Customer> list = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        StringBuffer sqlStmt = new StringBuffer(500);
....
....        
return list;
        }
```

Comment: Which target compiles your test classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CustomerTest class is clearly not in the classpath.  Have you checked your ${build}/classes directory?  If you are using something like a Maven project setup, your tests may actually compile to a directory like ${build}/test-classes.

UPDATE
See: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html#nested

This link suggests you should use:

```
     <batchtest fork="no" todir="${reports}">
        <fileset dir="${src_dir}" includes="**/CustomerTest.java"/>
     </batchtest>
```

Comment: My test classes are compiled in target not shown in my initial post. Here is the complete build.xml:

Comment: The createdist target depends on the compile. The compile target creates all the *.class files in the ${build}\classes\com\biscom\fadb8 folder.
I corrected the classpath_junit to point to the correct folder. 
Now am getting the following error:
  <error message="CustomerTest (wrong name: com/biscom/fadb8/CustomerTest)" type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CustomerTest (wrong name: com/biscom/fadb8/CustomerTest)

Comment: BTW, if I use fork="yes", get the same error, but a longer stacktrace:

   <error message="CustomerTest (wrong name: com/biscom/fadb8/CustomerTest)" type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CustomerTest (wrong name: com/biscom/fadb8/CustomerTest)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

Comment: You've left off the package name of your class and test class.  It appears to be com.biscom.fadb6.CustomerTest and you are trying to run CustomerTest.  See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html#nested for some nested batchtest/batchset examples.  If you use **/CustomerTest.java you will probably be set.  I refined my original answer with these updates.

Comment: thank you, that fixed the problem. Now am executing the tests